# An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (2 MB) that this server supports

Tags: image, drupal-7

Ok I got Drupal 7.19, mySQL 5.1.66-cll PHP 5.3.21

Now I searched for he above error and found various answers of various age, however it doesn't address, my problem.

I get the error for any file bigger than 100k
went through php.ini settings.php as well as account settings, which is now 5000k.
and max post and max file are way higher.

The site has only 2 image fields, the original as well as one other. It doesn't matter which one is used in a content, the field settings for the original one were never changed and the themed installation came with images larger than 500k.
While for the time I can live with resizing images before uploading, it nevertheless is a pain in the .... and I really would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem which i resolved via the `php.ini` file as well as the apache mod_security `user.conf` file.

My httpd is apache2, which has mod_security enabled, which also did not allow me to upload over 100k image file in Drupal. Apparently this is a common problem for the web-hosting provider (liquid web) because it took no more than 3 minutes to resolve.

First the `php.ini` file was altered (on CentOS it is in `/usr/local/lib/`) with lines:

```
;upload_tmp_dir = /tmp  (yes it has a semi-colon at the start)
```

and also the line:

```
session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

Second file that was altered is the `modsec2.user.conf` file located on (CentOS) at `/usr/local/apache/conf/`

(appended at the bottom of the file in the last 2 lines):

```
SecUploadDir /tmp
SecTmpDir  /tmp
```

Then `/etc/init.d/httpd restart` (or reload) apache and you should be able to bypass this limit for file uploads by mod_apache if it is enabled. Best of luck and please know that this is my first answer on stack so please be considerate.

Answer (score 0):

just you can request your hosting provider 
to added into the sites whitelist.conf file :

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
<LocationMatch .*>
SecRuleRemoveById 340147
</LocationMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: just you can request your hosting provider to added into the sites whitelist.conf file :
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
<LocationMatch .*>
SecRuleRemoveById 340147
</LocationMatch>
</IfModule>